# How to add checkboxes to a tree view in VS Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, checkbox, treeview, vscode-extensions

I am working on creating a vs code extension that has a tree view loading in the side panel. I need checkbox with each node of tree view. How can I achieve this? Following is an example of how I actually want to implement the checkbox.

[image]

Comment: you have to simulate it with images or use a WebviewView

Comment: @rioV8 Is this possible to create tree structure in this side panel using WebviewView?

Comment: yes everything you can construct in HTML is possible, with or without a GUI library